# How to enter a word in looping <td> in php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have table data which is taking data from foreach and looping through a for loop.(looping 3 times with different values from foreach)
I want to know that how can I put a word in last `<td>` ?

my code;

```
<?php
        foreach($halls_all_array AS $row){?>
        <td nowrap class="auto-style34" style="height: 30px; width: 20%" align="left">
                          time1-<?php echo format_time($row[$start]['time'])?>
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you need to add word in last <td>, right? @saku

Answer (score 0):

**Use :**

```
if($j == ($limit - 1)) {
    // last <td> here. You can add the text here.
}
```

**EDIT**

```
    <?php
    $count = count($halls_all_array);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($halls_all_array AS $row){
    ?>
            <td nowrap class="auto-style34" style="height: 30px; width: 20%" align="left">time1-<?php echo format_time($row[$start]['time'])?>
    <?php
            if(++$i === $count){
                //echo 'WORD TO PRINT';
            }
?>
            </td>
<?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I have edited the question .. the looping `<td >` is  done by foreach..not for loop please help @Ashish Choudhary

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

// first of all check $halls_all_array and $start are defined or not

```
<?php
$count=count($halls_all_array);
$i=1;
foreach($halls_all_array AS $row){
    echo'<td nowrap class="auto-style34" style="height: 30px; width: 20%" align="left">time1-'.format_time($row[$start]['time']);
    if($i == $count){
        //echo 'WORD TO PRINT';
    }
    echo'</td>';
    $i++;   
}
?>
```

Comment: I have edited the question .. the looping `<td >` is  done by foreach..not for loop please help @Mohammed Shafeek.C.S

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($halls_all_array AS $row){
    for($j=$start;$j<$limit;$j++){ ?>
   <td nowrap class="auto-style34" style="height: 30px; width: 20%"   align="left"> time1-<?php echo format_time($row[$j]['time'])
if($j==($limit-1)){ echo "word";}
?>
   </td>
    <?php
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I have edited the question .. the looping `<td >` is  done by foreach..not for loop please help @Sharmistha Das

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
    $length = count($halls_all_array);  // TAKE THE LENGTH OF ARRAY
    $i = 1;
    foreach($halls_all_array as $row){ ?> 
         <td nowrap class="auto-style34" style="height: 30px; width: 20%" align="left">
            <?php if($i < $length){ ?>
                  time1- <?php echo format_time($row[$start]['time']);?> 
              <?php }else{ 
                      echo "YOUR WORD...";   // Last Looping..
                      } ?>
         </td> 
<?php 
         $i++;      // INCREMENT THE COUNTER 
    } ?>
```

Comment: I have edited the question .. the looping <td > is done by foreach..not for loop please help @Sabin Chacko

Answer (score 0):

View

```
<?php foreach(... ) { ?>
     <td>loop td</td>
<?php } ; ?>
```

Comment: I want to add additional word in last `<td>` @WRDev

Comment: I have edited the question .. the looping <td > is done by foreach..not for loop please help @WRDev

Answer (score 0):

first get the last key from array

```
end($halls_all_array); // move the internal pointer to the end of the array

$last_key = key($halls_all_array);// fetches the key of the element pointed to by the internal pointer
```

try this code:

```
<?php
     /*get the last key*/
  end($halls_all_array);
  $last_key = key($halls_all_array);

  foreach($halls_all_array as $key => $row){?>
    <td nowrap class="auto-style34" style="height: 30px; width: 20%" align="left">
       time1-<?php echo format_time($row[$start]['time'])?>
   </td>
   <?php if ($last_key == $key): ?>
     <td><?php echo $row ?></td>
  <?php endif ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write code like this:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;  // start a counter
$total_count =   count($halls_all_array);  //total Counts
foreach($halls_all_array AS $row){?>
        <td nowrap class="auto-style34" style="height: 30px; width: 20%" align="left">
                time1-<?php echo format_time($row[$start]['time'])?>
                <?php if($total_count==$counter)  echo 'word'; ?> // you condition for last and word
        </td>
<?php 
$counter++;
} 
?>
```